# /usr/bin/expect inline multiline command

Tags: shell, command-line, command, expect

I have this command in a file `sign.sh`:

```
sudo openssl << EOF
engine dynamic ###long line here###
ca -engine pkcs11 ###long line here###
EOF
```

I have used this in `/usr/bin/expect` like this

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 10

spawn "sign.sh"

expect "Enter PKCS#11 key PIN for SIGN key:" { send "pass_here\r" }

interact
```

This works. But I need to "one line" this whole thing by replacing `spawn "sign.sh"` with `spawn sudo openssl << EOF... etc`

How do I get that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
set script "
sudo openssl << EOF
engine dynamic ...
ca -engine pkcs11 ...
EOF
"

spawn bash -c $script
```